# How to load dynamically a jar at classpath with java 11

Tags: jar, runtime, load, java-11, urlclassloader

To load dynamically a jar to classpath I used to use the following code with Java 8.

```
File file = new File(jarPath);
URL u =  f.toURI().toURL();     
URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
Class urlClass = URLClassLoader.class;
Method method = urlClass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(urlClassLoader, new Object[]{u});
```

However using Java 11 does not work anymore. I have tried some solution provided in the internet but none of them works for me.
Please could you help me to resolve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing (since you didn't say one way or the other) that the cast to `URLClassLoader` is failing? Even if I'm correct you should post a [mre] demonstrating the problem and the error(s) you're getting. Also note that simply saying "I have tried some solution [...] but none of them works for me" doesn't say much. _What_ are the solutions you tried? _How_ did they not work? If you don't specify then you risk getting the same exact solutions again. See [ask].

Comment: You have to create a *new* `URLClassLoader` instead of trying to hack the system class loader.

Comment: Loading classes dynamically in Java 11 has no difference to Java 8: [How should I load Jars dynamically at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime)

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68380968/java-11-issue-with-adding-dependency-jars-at-runtime